# ionic cordova - How to solve error in ionic v4 that is "An error occurred while running subprocess cordova"?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

shows me When running `ionic cordova build android --release`

[image]

i also tried `ionic cordova build android --prod` and --verbose

[image]

it used to run without a hitch but after Pull our project from git hub
and then this problem came to me

How should i do?

`ionic info`

[image]

PS. already keep trying `ionic cordova platform rm/add android`

Comment: add code of `AppModule`, where it refers to `ChartModule`. and please, don't post errors as screenshots.

Comment: @MartinZeitler
Sorry it's my first time
`ChartModule` is in `app.module.ts`
`@NgModule({
import: [
ChartModule.forRoot(
   require('highcharts'),
   require('highcharts/highcharts-more')),
]})`

Comment: https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/254

Comment: @MartinZeitler
Thank you for the information but it has not solved.